# DotCMS - adding multiple instances of the same container in template designer

Tags: content-management-system, dotcms

Is it possible to add more than one instance of the same container in the DotCMS template designer? This is without using advanced templates.

I am using a container called Announcement. Its content is a piece of text which then is displayed as an announcement.

Upon adding an instance of the Announcement container to a template through the template designer, it is no longer selectable from the list of containers when I try to add another. Is this intended?

Adding multiple containers of the same type through the advanced template editor is fine so I can't imagine this being a technical limitation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As of 5.1, yes, you can have multiple versions of a container in a template.